# How to access a member in the subset in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

I have set `i/1*7/` and parameter `u(i) /1 15,2 5,3 15,4 30,5 21,6 30,7 11/`

I want to find maximum element of `u(i)` , i use `'smax'` , I write this code:

```
  set j/1*7/;
  parameter u(i) /1 15,2 5,3 15,4 30,5 21,6 30,7 11/;
  scalar max_val;
  max_val=smax(j,u(j));
```

To find the index of maximum element, I wrote this

```
  set posmax(j)  'position of largest element on deg(j)';
  posmax(j) = deg(j) = max_val ;
```

There are two maximum members here, but I just want one.for example iwant to have posmax=6 , or posmax=4 . but i dont want posmax = 6,7.

What command should i use?

How can I access the first member?

In general, how can I access a particular member in a subset?

i write `posmax('1')` but i get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scalars mypos;
Mypos=smin (j$posmax(j) ,j.val);
```